# How to insert array to mysql one word one row?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I am using Zend Framework.
I would like to insert array `$color = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');` into mysql, one color to one row.
How do I code this in my model file?

### Controller

```
public function addAction()
{
    $this->view->Title = "Add Colors";
    $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title, 'PREPEND');

    $form = new Form_Color();
    $form->submit->setLabel('Add');
    $this->view->form = $form;
    
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            $color = $form->getValue('color');
            $colors = new Model_DbTable_Colors();
            $colors->addColor($color);
            
            $this->_redirect('/');
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Model

```
public function addColor($color)
{
     $data = explode("\n",$color);
    
     // How to coding for insert one color one row ????

}
```

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a foreach() on the array that gives you explode() and then foreach item issue a Add command on your DbTable model.

Answer (score 0):

if $color is an array you can do a foreach loop

```
public function addColor($color) {
   foreach($color as $color_key=>$color_data) {
      // $color_data is the value like red, green, blue
      // $color_key is the index of the array that holds the color
      echo "The array index is: ".$color_key." for Color: ".$color_data."<br />\n";
   }
}
```